# replacing column values with Y and N

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table which contains column Flag with values(Y,N) ,when I write select Query it should return me result as (Yes,No) .how to achieve that????Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE Flag 
           WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Yes' 
           ELSE 'No' 
       END AS Flag 
FROM TableName
```

Syntax:

```
CASE column_name  
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1  
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2  
    ...  
    ELSE result  
END
```

Read more about CASE [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE Flag
           WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
           ELSE 'No'
       END AS Flag
FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try if condition apart from casing as suggested above:

```
SELECT IF(flag='Y','Yes','No') FROM mytable;
```